# How to upgrade hboot

Tags: htc-desire

I have an HTC Desire and my end game is to get [custom md partitions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=806321). I'm at step one trying to get S-OFF. I've downloaded the tool from revolutionary.io and it tells me my device is:

```
Found your device: HTC Desire (bravo-0.75.0000, Android: 2.3.5, ROM version: bravo-user)

Your device: bravo, with HBOOT 0.75.0000 is not supported at this time.
```

So I've looked into how to upgrade the HBOOT and I read that I need S-OFF first? It's a classic chicken and egg scenario. Where do I go from here?

Comment: What makes you think a newer `hboot` version would make your device supported? I guess your real question should not be *how to upgrade hboot*, but *how to s-off your device* -- it's a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/16575).

Comment: Because the form at http://revolutionary.io has a select field for HBOOT version with the values {0.93.0001, 1.02.0001} only. It may be an XY problem, but as I state, I don't know which is the X and which the Y

Comment: OK, that information was missing in your question (maybe you edit it directly into it, so it gets more obvious). Still, as your target is to get S-Off, so that's your X. Your question is about one possible solution, which is Y. So if you want to solve X, better ask for X -- which might bring you to your goal faster, as more alternatives might be available.